# When mapStateToProps in create create a new axios call

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, axios

I have created a Reactjs component that receives a mapStateToProps function call. Everything works fine except the ajax call using Axios.

The class on a mapStateToProps update needs to call the server and add its payload to the state of the component and update the textarea.

The error I am getting from the console is,

```
ReactDOMIDOperations.js:47 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Below is what I have so far. Can anyone show me how to fix this issue?

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import ApiCalls from "../../../utils/ApiCalls";

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { passFilePath: state.passFilePath };
};



/**
 *  This component is a template to display
 *  widgets of information
 */
class IdeTextEditorClass extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      newData: [],
      pathData: []
    }
  }


  /**
   *  Received request from server add it to 
   *  react component so that it can be rendered
   */
  componentDidUpdate() {

    try {
      this.setState({ pathData: this.props.passFilePath[this.props.passFilePath.length - 1] });
    } catch (err) {
      this.setState({ pathData: '' });
    }

    console.log('path', this.state.pathData.data);
    ApiCalls.readSassFile(this.state.pathData.data)
      .then(function (serverData) {
       this.setState({ newData: serverData[0].data })
      }.bind(this));
  }


  render() {

    try {
      this.state.newData
    } catch (err) {
      this.setState({ newData: '' });
    }


    return (
      <fieldset>
        <input type="text" value={this.state.pathData.data} />
        <textarea id="ide-text-area" name="ide-text-area" value={this.state.newData} /></fieldset>
    )
  }
}

const IdeTextEditor = connect(mapStateToProps)(IdeTextEditorClass);
export default IdeTextEditor;
```

Comment: When you `setState` it triggers `componentDidUpdate`. You're creating an endless loop.

Comment: Ok, So what method should I be using to update the component?

Comment: One option is to create a conditional statement that will check something then run your `setState` code. Such as `if (!this.state.newData.length) { /* call for newData */ }`.

Comment: Also, you should understand how the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method works: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

Comment: Thanks, I have just read it and can see what I was doing wrong. The condition placed around setting state works great.

Comment: You should be writing selectors and relying on the `connect` function to tell your component when to update.  That's one of the most powerful features of the library.

Comment: `You should be writing selectors` do you mean this https://redux.js.org/introduction/learningresources#selectors. If this best practice I will happy go and findout the best way to do this =)

Answer (score 0):

```
class IdeTextEditorClass extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    /*
    based on your original code it seems the default data should be empty string ,as you set them to be empty string when you cannot get data from server. 
    */
    this.state = {
      newData: '',
      pathData: ''
    }
  }


  /**
   *  Received request from server add it to 
   *  react component so that it can be rendered
   */
  componentDidMount() {
    try {
      this.setState({ pathData: this.props.passFilePath[this.props.passFilePath.length - 1] });
    } catch (err) {
      this.setState({ pathData: '' });
    }

    console.log('path', this.state.pathData.data);
    ApiCalls.readSassFile(this.state.pathData.data)
      .then(function (serverData) {
       this.setState({ newData: serverData[0].data })
      }.bind(this));
  }


  render() {
    //by default your newData is already empty string. so skip the checking here.

    let path = this.state.pathData ? this.state.pathData.data : '';    

    return (
      <fieldset>
        <input type="text" value={path} />
        <textarea id="ide-text-area" name="ide-text-area" value={this.state.newData} /></fieldset>
    )
  }
}
```

Explanation:
The major change is to change `componentDidUpdate` to `componentDidMount`.
Putting the data initializing logic in `componentDidMount` because:

1. called only once, thus avoiding the endless update loop mentioned in the comments. Also, initialization logic is usually expected here.
2. this method is called after initial render, so you can at least display something to user during the wait for data (from server). for example, in your `render` method, you can check `newData` and if it is not available, display a loading icon. Then React calls `componentDidMount`, and fetch your data -> update state -> trigger render again -> displays your input / text area using new data fetched from server. Of course, if you don't want to bother showing a loading icon, it is also fine, because your view will probably be updated quickly, when the ajax call returns.